# py2exe no module named lgamma

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, py2exe

I am trying to create an exe file for a python file. py2exe creates the executable, but when I run the executable, I get the following traceback:

```
C:\Users\gkumar7\Desktop\AL_gui-master\AL_gui-master\dist>app.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "learning_curve.pyc", line 13, in <module>
  File "sklearn\metrics\__init__.pyc", line 34, in <module>
  File "sklearn\metrics\scorer.pyc", line 30, in <module>
  File "sklearn\metrics\cluster\__init__.pyc", line 8, in <module>
  File "sklearn\metrics\cluster\supervised.pyc", line 18, in <module>
  File "sklearn\metrics\cluster\expected_mutual_info_fast.pyc", line 12, in <mod
ule>
  File "sklearn\metrics\cluster\expected_mutual_info_fast.pyc", line 10, in __lo
ad
  File "expected_mutual_info_fast.pyx", line 1, in init sklearn.metrics.cluster.
expected_mutual_info_fast (sklearn\metrics\cluster\expected_mutual_info_fast.c:5
007)
ImportError: No module named lgamma
```

Here is my setup.py file:

```
dll_excludes = ['MSVCP90.dll', 'OLEAUT32.dll', 'USER32.dll', 'IMM32.dll', 'SHELL32.dll',
                'ole32.dll', 'COMDLG32.dll', 'COMCTL32.dll', 'ADVAPI32.dll', 'mfc90.dll', 'msvcrt.dll',
                'WS2_32.dll', 'WINSPOOL.DRV', 'GDI32.dll', 'VERSION.dll', 'KERNEL32.dll', 'ntdll.dll']

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, matplotlib, numpy
setup(console=['app.py'],
      data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),
      options = {"py2exe": {
                          "dll_excludes": dll_excludes,
                          "includes": ['scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation',
                                        'scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx']
                         }
              }, )
```

I have also tried cx_freeze, but kept receiving similar errors. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Include `sklearn.utils.lgamma` in your py2exe setup file.